# Creating a time dependent table in SQL for master data (system-versioned temporal tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server

For a datawarehouse environment in SQL Server I have a master data sheet. However, I want to get to see all the changes over time.

Example of the current dataset:

| id | Department | number of employees | datefrom | dateto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sales | 14 | 2023-01-12 | 9999-12-31 |
| 2 | finance | 2 | 2023-01-12 | 9999-12-31 |

The data set we get is like:

| id | Department | number of employees | modifying date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sales | 14 | 2023-01-12 |
| 2 | finance | 2 | 2023-01-12 |

In this case, the modifying date is the date from of the current data set. Now the data set has been updated and the data set looks like:

| id | Department | number of employees | modifying date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sales | 18 | 2023-01-14 |
| 2 | finance | 9 | 2023-01-19 |

Now I want to update the current data set so it look like the following data set:

| id | Department | number of employees | datefrom | dateto |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sales | 14 | 2023-01-12 | 2023-01-13 |
| 1 | sales | 18 | 2023-01-14 | 9999-12-31 |
| 2 | finance | 2 | 2023-01-12 | 2023-01-18 |
| 2 | finance | 9 | 2023-01-19 | 9999-12-31 |

Is this possible with system-versioned temporal tables from SQL or do I need to write a stored procedure?

Comment: The big restriction with system-versioned temporal tables is that they're *system-versioned* -- there is no support for user-supplied timestamps. While you can use these by turning off the history table, inserting your custom data and turning it back on, this is mainly useful for transitioning existing tables to a new setup, and not at all convenient (in terms of code, locking and performance) if it has to be done for every change. The big question therefore is whether you're OK with your "modifying date" being the DW row modification date, rather than a business value.